# balance positives and negatives in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix where the last column has some floats in it. Around 70% of the numbers are positive, while 30% are negative. I'd like to remove some rows with a positive number so that the result matrix has approxiamtely the same number of positive and negative numbers in the last column. I'd like to remove the positives rows randomly.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(30).reshape(10, 3)

x[[0,1,2,],[2,2,2]] = x[[0,1,2],[2,2,2]] * -1

a = np.where(x[:,2] > 0)[0]

n_pos = np.sum(x[:,2] > 0)
n_neg = np.sum(x[:,2] < 0)

n_to_remove = n_pos - n_neg
np.random.shuffle(a)

new_x = np.delete(x, a[:n_to_remove], axis = 0)
```

Result:

```
>>> x

array([[ 0,  1, -2],
       [ 3,  4, -5],
       [ 6,  7, -8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26],
       [27, 28, 29]])
>>> new_x
array([[ 0,  1, -2],
       [ 3,  4, -5],
       [ 6,  7, -8],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [27, 28, 29]])
```

I think this is easier to do with arrays than matrices, let me know if you need a solution with matrices.